# What kind of loading screen should I have

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, progress-bar

I'm making a navigation based application.  When the user selects a row on the table view, it goes to the next table. However, depending on how many entries are on the table view, this can be instantaneous, or it can take a while.

Something needs to be shown to the user that the program is working and is not frozen. I was thinking of bringing up a different view with a progress bar on it, but that won't be useful for situations when the next table will load immediately.

I was also thinking of overlaying some kind of progress meter on top of the first table, but instead of a bar it's a circle. Is that possible?

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD. Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like what I'm looking for, but can't get the demo to work.